# How to get any data from site for android app

Tags: android, database, api

I'm trying to create android application in which user will be receiving notification every hour with some short string info on his choice, like some random word from urban dictionary, or some random grammar rule. But the problem is I cant find any tips about how to get that random info and parse it into my app. For example urban dictionary have api only for getting results by Word query. Maybe there is any sites with useful info that have api which will be easier to use in my app or maybe i should use any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scrape the website. Use below code to get the website in html format and scrape it using [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/)

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.urbandictionary.com");
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
// response has the website in html format
```

But make sure you contact the website and let them know you are doing it. I am not sure about the legality behind it.